# How to align a JTextField that it is always on the far right side of the window?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextfield, contentpane

I have a normal content pane in Java (IDE: Eclipse) and a `JTextField`.

Now I want the text field to always be on the far right, even if the size of the window changes. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: refer: https://www.miglayout.com/ this could help

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: For the best advice, please post ASCII art or a simple drawing of the **complete** GUI as seen by the user at the initial size as well as when more width and height have been added (to show how extra space is assigned or used).

Answer (score 1):

One way to is nest panels with different layout manager.

The default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout (unless Eclipse changes it, in which case you should set it back to a BorderLayout.

Then you can:

1. create a `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout` that is right aligned.
2. add the text field to this panel.
3. add this panel to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` of the content pane.
4. add you main panel containing other components to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`.